# Prevent duplication with a composite visitor

Tags: c++, generics

I currently have two visitors that both work correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct VisitorA
{
  void DoSomething(){}
};

struct VisitorB
{
  void DoSomething(){}
};

template <typename TVisitor>
static void RunAlgorithm(TVisitor& visitor);

int main()
{
  VisitorA visitorA;
  VisitorB visitorB;
  RunAlgorithm(visitorA);
  RunAlgorithm(visitorB);
}

template <typename TVisitor>
void RunAlgorithm(TVisitor& visitor)
{
  visitor.DoSomething();
}
```

Now I want to apply both visitors in the algorithm. I've seen a "composite" visitor that stores multiple visitors and simply forwards the call to each of them. To do this, it seems like I have to make a "ParentVisitor" class and derive from it just so I can store a ParentVisitor* in a container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct VisitorParent
{
  void DoSomething(){}
};

struct VisitorA : public VisitorParent
{
  void DoSomething(){}
};

struct VisitorB : public VisitorParent
{
  void DoSomething(){}
};

struct VisitorComposite : public VisitorParent
{
  void DoSomething()
  {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < Visitors.size(); ++i)
      {
      Visitors[i]->DoSomething();
      }
  }
  std::vector<VisitorParent*> Visitors;
};

static void RunAlgorithm(VisitorParent& visitor);

int main()
{
//   VisitorA visitor;
//   RunAlgorithm(visitor);

  VisitorA visitorA;
  VisitorB visitorB;
  VisitorComposite visitorComposite;
  visitorComposite.Visitors.push_back(&visitorA);
  visitorComposite.Visitors.push_back(&visitorB);
  RunAlgorithm(visitorComposite);
}

void RunAlgorithm(VisitorParent& visitor)
{
  visitor.DoSomething();
}
```

The problem with doing this is that if the visitors have some duplicated functionality, it will be performed twice. I thought of moving the duplicated code to the VisitorParent, but then I'm not sure how to say "only run the parent code for one of the visitors, and just don't run anything for the rest" for the duplicated sections. This seems to "manual" - is there a better mechanism for applying two (or more) visitors?

Comment: Isn't `Visitor` a misnomer here? I would rather call it a policy class.

Comment: If it traverses a polymorphic tree and derives from an abstract base class, it's a Visitor.  The lack of detail in the code examples makes it hard to tell though.

Comment: @JeffreyHantin What does he need an abstract base class for if the visitor type is a template parameter?

Comment: @pmr it seems like an unfortunate terminology clash - I am calling a "visitor" in the sense of this idea: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/visitor_concepts.html

Also, the abstract base class is just so I can store a vector<visitor>.

Comment: @pmr It's not a clash -- boost's essential concept of a visitor is essentially the same as the Gang of Four concept, as a way of plugging varying functionality into a graph traversal algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, then, that besides the abstract base visitor class, you actually need *four* concrete visitors in total:

1. one containing the common operations factored out of A and B
2. one containing the operations unique to A
3. one containing the operations unique to B
4. one compositor that can call multiple other visitors via the abstract base class

Then the role of the original visitor A is handled by composing common with uniqueA, the role of visitor B is handled by composing common with uniqueB, and the combined operation is handled by composing common, uniqueA, and uniqueB.

Deduplication can be done in a factory function for compositors, but you may not want to "bake in" deduplication in the compositor class in order to retain a little more flexibility.

Comment: Nice, this seems pretty reasonable. Is the CompositeVisitor I showed the right way to go with your #4 then (i.e. making the abstract base class with the same interface just so I can store a vector<VisitorParent*> ?

Comment: @David Pretty much spot-on.  Templates only provide compile-time polymorphism, which is of no use to build a heterogeneous collection.  The abstract base class provides the required run-time polymorphism so you can meaningfully talk about the concept of a `vector<VisitorParent*>`.

Answer (score 0):

With the visitor pattern, you don't really expect anything to "break" if you run it.  So when you run something twice it should probably work.  *Whether* you run something twice is a higher level concern than the visitor, so it shouldn't be influencing the visitor's design.

So manual is probably good in this case.

The role of the composite probably should be a controller.  It might know that if one visitor succeeds that the other one is not appropriate to run too.  Adding a return value to your visitors would give the composite the feedback it needs to control what gets run.  The controller's concern is what to run, the visitor stays dumb.

Comment: Where does the controller live? In the CompositeVisitor? Or does the Algorithm need to use it? I did some searching and the only "controller" I found is in the model-view-controller idea - is this the same "controller" you are referring to? Do you have a good link/example I can check out?

Comment: @DavidDoria Oh, I should have been clearer.  I didn't mean it in a "controller is a pattern" sense.  I'll look tomorrow and see if there is a pattern that is close.  Really it is just another class that collects behavior from your other two visitors.  It uses the visitors' behavior and controls when one or the other is called.